# JGit ProgressMonitor reports wrong number of tasks

Tags: jgit, progressmonitor

I am using JGit libs to implement basic git operations.

Javadoc for `ProgressMonitor`:
http://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/ProgressMonitor.html

Here, you can see the log when I use a `ProgressMonitor` for `git clone` (implementation in the end):

- log start

  - Total tasks: 2
  - Task started: remote: Enumerating objects with total work: 0
  - Task started: remote: Counting objects with total work: 56
  - Task started: remote: Compressing objects with total work: 46
  - Task started: Receiving objects with total work: 56
  - Task ended: Receiving objects
  - Task started: Resolving deltas with total work: 1
  - Task ended: Resolving deltas
  - Task started: Checking out files with total work: 23
  - Task ended: Checking out files
- log ended

**Now the question:**

According to the method `start`, there are 2 tasks, but the method `beginTask` is reporting 6 tasks started and the method `endTask` is reporting 3 tasks ended... Can anybody explain to me this magic?
The cloning process itself finished successfully.

Below you can see the implementation of `ProgressMonitor` with methods writing to the log.

```java
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ProgressMonitor;

public class MyProgressMonitor implements ProgressMonitor {

    String currentTaskTitle;

    @Override
    public void start(int totalTasks) {
        System.out.println("Total tasks: " + totalTasks);
    }

    @Override
    public void beginTask(String title, int totalWork) {
        currentTaskTitle = title;

        System.out.println("Task started: " + title + " with total work: " + totalWork);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(int completed) {

    }

    @Override
    public void endTask() {
        System.out.println("Task ended: " + currentTaskTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug, at least in the progress book-keeping of the `CloneCommand`. Did you try other commands that accept a progress monitor? I suggest to file a bug report here: https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/support/

Comment: Reported as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568425
Also, I have tested git fetch and there are also some discrepancies:
Total tasks: 2, started 5 and ended 2